# In R, aggregate statistics with data.table when the group by variable is a string

Tags: r, string, group-by, arguments, data.table

I got this data.table set :

```
set.seed(1234)
r=100
ref=c("banana","chocolate","apple")
ref2=c("florida","california")
products=sample(ref,r,TRUE)
cities=sample(ref2,r,TRUE)
quantity=sample(seq(1:5),100,TRUE)
dt=data.table(products,quantity,cities)
head(dt,5)

  products quantity     cities
1:    apple        3    florida
2:   banana        5    florida
3:   banana        3    florida
4:    apple        2 california
5:    apple        5    Florida
```

I want a function which take the index of the group by variable as an argument. Like this :

```
sumfn=function(dt,index){
  var_group=c("products","cities")[index]
  res=dt[,list(Q=sum(quantity)),by=list(var_group)]
  return(res)
}
```

So that, if I ran this command :

```
count_dt=sumfn(dt,1)
```

My output would be :

```
    products   Q
1: chocolate  72
2:    banana  91
3:     apple 136
```

However, when I do run the command above, instead, I get this error message :

```
Error in `[.data.table`(dt, , list(Q = sum(quantity)), by = list(var_group)) : 
  The items in the 'by' or 'keyby' list are length (1). Each must be same length as rows in x or number of rows returned by i (100).
```

Anyone know how to fix that? I'm stuck with this problem for an hour.

Comment: What gave you the idea that you should wrap `var_group` in a list?

Comment: You don't need to use a list and you want to include a parameter `with=FALSE`:   `res=dt[,list(Q=sum(quantity)),by=var_group,with=FALSE]`

Comment: You may need `c` instead of `list` or just `var_group`.  `c` could be used when you are combining with other variables

Comment: Please, use `set.seed` before creating dummy data randomly, e.g., by `sample` or `runif`. Otherwise you can't compare the results.

Answer (score 2):

Remove `list` in the `by`clause, i.e.,

```
sumfn <- function(dt, index) {
    var_group <- c("products", "cities")[index]
    res <- dt[, list(Q = sum(quantity)), by = var_group]
    return(res)
}
```

and you will get

```
sumfn(dt,1)
    products   Q
1:     apple 116
2:    banana  83
3: chocolate 102
```

Comment: thks but actually i need it to get wrapped for some reasons. It's a fragment of a more complicated script.